# How to sum an array of strings, representing ints

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, casting

How to sum such an Array

`[ '',
  '4490449',
  '2478',
  '1280990',
  '22296892',
  '244676',
  '1249',
  '13089',
  '0',
  '0',
  '0\n' ]`

If I call something like that `['','4490449', ... , '0\n' ].reduce(function(t,s){ return t+s)` on that array, the stings are joined and not summed.

I've tried some casting with `parseInt()` but this results in `NaN` :)

Comment: `''` doesn't really represent an integer; how do you expect it to be handled?

Comment: I mean '' can stand for zero or?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to assure that the values you are summing are integers.  Here's one possible solution:

```
var ary=[ '', '4490449', '2478', '1280990', '22296892', 
          '244676', '1249', '13089', '0', '0', '0\n' ];

console.log(
  ary
    .map( function(elt){ // assure the value can be converted into an integer
      return /^\d+$/.test(elt) ? parseInt(elt) : 0; 
    })
    .reduce( function(a,b){ // sum all resulting numbers
      return a+b
    })
)​;
```

which prints '28329823' to the console.

See fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/hF6xv/

Comment: I think you should remove the `$` from that regex; `parseInt` ignores trailing non-digits (e.g. `'32a'` becomes `32`), and the OP's example includes `'0\n'` as one element. (Granted, your version will convert `'0\n'` to `0`, but that's mostly by coincidence.)

Comment: While what you say is true, I believe the expectation is that the strings are supposed to represent numeric integer values, which `0\n` does not.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work ok:

```
var arry = [ 'asdf', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'ham10am' ];

var res = arry.reduce(function(prev, curr){
    return (Number(prev) || 0) + (Number(curr) || 0);
});

console.log(res); // prints 45
```

Comment: This also allows for decimals to be added in.

Comment: what do the || preceding the 0 in this function mean?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var sum = 0,
    arr = [ '', '1', '2', '3.0','4\n', '0x10' ],
    i = arr.length;

while( i-- ) {
    // include radix otherwise last element gets interpreted as 16
    sum += parseInt( arr[i], 10 ) || 0; 
}

console.log( sum ) // sum => 10 as 3.0 and 4\n were successfully parsed
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5QfG2/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You're correct in using parseInt.

But you need to use it for each of the reduce arguments.

Furthermore, you also need to check if the result of each parseInt is a number, because if not, the function will try to sum a number with NaN and all the other sums will end up being NaN as well.

Mozilla's ECMAscript [documentation on parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) says:

> If the first character cannot be converted to a number, parseInt
>   returns NaN.

Then, to avoid getting NaN to spoil your goal, you could implement it like this:

```
function parseIntForSum(str) {
    var possibleInteger = parseInt(str);
    return isNaN(possibleInteger) ? 0 : possibleInteger;
}

function sum(f, s) {
    return parseIntForSum(f) + parseIntForSum(s);
}

window.alert('sum = ' + [ '', '4490449', '2478', '1280990', '22296892', '244676', '1249', '13089', '0', '0', '0\n' ].reduce(sum)​​​);​
```

Here's a jsfiddle with it working: http://jsfiddle.net/cLA7c/

Answer (score 0):

You have some values in your array which are not integers. Let's assume they all are, then you can do :

```
['4490449', '2478', '1280990', '22296892', '244676', '1249', '13089'].reduce( 
    function(t, s) { 
        return parseInt(t) + parseInt(s); 
    }
);
```

Comment: No that's what I've tried before
```[ '', '4490449', '2478', '1280990', '22296892', '244676', '1249', '13089', '0', '0', '0\n' ].reduce( 
...     function(t, s) { 
.....         return parseInt(t) + parseInt(s); 
.....     }
... );
NaN
```

Comment: Read just before the code : "You have some values in your array which are not integers". `''` is not an integer, neither does `'0\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.List;

public class MixedSum {

 /*
  * Assume input will be only of Integer o String type
  */
  public int sum(List<?> mixed) {
    
    // A new array to store all the elements in the mixed list after converting them to integers
    int[] newIntList = new int[mixed.size()];
    
    // Variable to store sum of all elements in our new array
    int sum = 0;
    
    // Loop through the mixed list and convert all integers to strings and then back to string
    //(mixed.get(i) + "") converts all integers to strings and leave strings as strings
    // parseInt() function converts everything back to integers 
    for(int i = 0; i < mixed.size(); i++){
      newIntList[i] = Integer.parseInt(mixed.get(i) + "");
    }
    
    // Loops through the array and sum up all elements
    for(int i = 0; i < newIntList.length; i++){
      sum += newIntList[i];
    }
    
    //returns sum
    return sum;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.