# How can I find the sum of an array?

Tags: javascript

say that I have:

```
var arr = ['-1254', '+2343']
```

I want my sum to be `1,089`

I tried `parseInt(arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0))` but it returns 0.

How can find the sum of arr?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the sum of an array of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers)

Comment: You need to convert the strings to numbers first. Try `arr.map(Number).reduce ...`

Comment: Use `parseInt` first then reduce later. You are trying to parse the array which is invalid

Comment: duplicate [How to sum an array of strings, representing ints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13128610/how-to-sum-an-array-of-strings-representing-ints)

Comment: @JorgeGuerreiro, thanks for your answer, unfortunately it doesn't because I have an array of strings. so the sum would turn out to be '0-1254+2343'

Comment: And since you already know the issue based on your last comment: [Adding two numbers concatenates them instead of calculating the sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496531/adding-two-numbers-concatenates-them-instead-of-calculating-the-sum)

Answer (score 1):

You got 0 because in `arr.reduce()` initial a value is 0 number type. but b is current value that is `'-1245'` is string. So that's why it's not calculate.

If you want to calculate it properly you need to make `b` as an integer. Like this.

`var result = arr.reduce((a, b) => a + parseInt(b), 0)`

then log this.
Thank you

Answer (score -1):

you need to convert string into number first.

```js
var arr = ['-1254', '+2343']

arr.reduce((a, b) => a *1 + b * 1,0)
```